# El reloj que muestro en un Label de Windows Forms C# me sale en formato de 12 horas

Tags: c#, windows-forms

empiezo a ser pesado

Es que me ayudaron a componer un código para un reloj, y me funicona todo a la perfección, pero la hora me aparece en formato de 12 horas.

Habría alguna posibilidad de poner la hora en formato 24 horas ?

este es mi código:

```
//Capturamos la hora y la escribimos en el TextBox.  
        lblReloj.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm:ss");
        lblHoras.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("hh");
        lblHoras.Visible = false;
        lblMinutos.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("mm");
        lblMinutos.Visible = false;
        lblSegundos.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("ss");
        lblSegundos.Visible = false;
        lblFecha.Text = DateTime.Now.ToLongDateString();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cuando utilizas [las cadena de formato personalizadas para fecha/hora](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings) puedes indicar el tipo de "formato hora", con el especificador de formato "h" u "H", entonces:

- "h": La hora, usando un reloj de 12 horas de 1 a 12.
- "hh": La hora, usando un reloj de 12 horas de 01 a 12.
- "H": La hora, usando un reloj de 24 horas de 0 a 23.
- "HH": La hora, usando un reloj de 24 horas de 00 a 23.

Por ejemplo, en tu caso estas utilizando

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm:ss");
```

Deberias cambiar la parte de hora por:

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss");
```

Enlace que te puede servir de ayuda o guía

- [Cadenas con formato de fecha y hora personalizado](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings)
- [Cadenas con formato de fecha y hora estándar](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-date-and-time-format-strings)

Comment: Vaya, habéis contestado a la vez, pues sí, muchas gracias, me funcionó.